# Tooltipster implementation problems

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm desperately trying to set up tooltipster on my WP website.

Page: www.jakobenglund.com/tooltip

I've asked the developer, but he says "I'll see 404 if I use Firebug." He forwarded me here, so help would be appreciated.

I've found similar questions and tried to edit my code respectively, with no success. Please help me.

My code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wp-content/themes/blogify/css/tooltipster.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/blogify/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.tooltip').tooltipster();
        });
    </script>
```

Script page: http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#demos